# How do I create a JWT for automated testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, security, owin, jwt

**Context**

Our project has a collection of independent http services that work together we have

1. authentication service
2. service A
3. service B
4. service C

the purpose of A, B, & C is not important for this discussion. other than they interact with one another.

Authentication service is our implementation of Owin.Identity. Service A came online first and we (most likely) did not implement security integration correctly. We had to implement our own `MachineKeyProtector` to uprotect the identity and set the request context principal

```
var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new MachineKeyProtector());
var ticket = secureDataFormat.Unprotect(accessToken);
request.GetRequestContext().Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(ticket.Identity);
```

This already seems incorrect. I thought

```
//startup.cs
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

//web.config
//all our services share the same machine key
<machineKey decryptionKey="..." validationKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

took care of security.

then comes the issue of automated tests. We are using `Owin.Testing` to mock HTTP calls and run integration tests. To get this to work, we need to create a JWT and we are currently using this code

```
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
var protected = new MachineKeyProtector().Protect(ticket);
new TicketDataFormat(protected);
```

again using our `MachineKeyProtector` implementation. All of this is working but it doesn't seem right. I would have through `Owin.Security.OAuth` (or JWT?) would handle this for us.

We created `MachineKeyProtector` as a way to generate JWT tokens for our automated tests.

**Questions/Problems**

1. How can we generate a JWT without implementing our own `MachineKeyProtector`. I would assume there is a `JwtTokenizer.Create(new Claims Identity());` call we could use to generate the authentication token, but I haven't been able to find it.
2. How do we configure security in service A, B, & C so the request principal is set without us setting it explicitly?

I tried to keep the context as simple as possible while providing some insight into where we currently are. If more information is need please ask.